# Excel download process die the page in case of large dataset in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, ado.net, webforms

I have developed an application where i am getting data from database ,binding it to an Infragistics grid and then **downloading excel** using its export utility.

There is a problem with this approach when data set is large (say 20000 records or more), it 'll take long time to process and **download**, and usually it 'll die the page and show blank page to user.

Is there any better approach to handle this issue and make reasonable improvements in excel **download** process?

Code is like something below:

```
    public void LoadExcelPostingData()
        {
            try
            {
                query = "Some complex query here with up to 10 columns";
                dt.Clear();
                dt = new DataTable();
                db2.GetDataTable(query, CommandType.Text, ref dt);

                grdJurdata.DataSource = dt;
                grdJurdata.DataBind();

                ExportToExcel();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblresult.Text = "Grd Err : " + ex.Message;
            }

        }  
   private void ExportToExcel()
        {
            try
            {
                // Infragistics built in excel export utility
                UltraWebGridExcelExporter2.Export(grdJurdata);            
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {  }

        }
```

Comment: Simply you need a good mechanism to download large excel files. Right?

Comment: Share your code as well

Comment: @freak, I am asking/searching for good mechanism !!!

Comment: So what mechanism you are using right now?

Comment: Please see the code in question description.

Comment: What is the version of `Infragistics` you are using?

Comment: Its version is : Version=8.3.20083.1009

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31752/discussion-between-freak-and-waqas-ali)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding file download Microsoft's MSDN provide a [detailed explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478985.aspx)

- Get the response
- With the response, Set the content type to "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM" (it means there's no application              to open the file).
- Set the header to "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + + "\"".
- Write the file content into the response.
- Close the response.

Also keep in mind that never use Ajax request to download file because for file transfer , It needs complete PostBack Request
 Here is the sample code given on MSDN

```
<%
try
{
   System.String filename = "myFile.txt";

   // set the http content type to "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM
   Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";

   // initialize the http content-disposition header to
   // indicate a file attachment with the default filename
   // "myFile.txt"
   System.String disHeader = "Attachment; Filename=\"" + filename +
      "\"";
   Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);

   // transfer the file byte-by-byte to the response object
   System.IO.FileInfo fileToDownload = new
      System.IO.FileInfo("C:\\downloadJSP\\DownloadConv\\myFile.txt");
   Response.Flush();
   Response.WriteFile(fileToDownload.FullName);}
catch (System.Exception e)
// file IO errors
{
   SupportClass.WriteStackTrace(e, Console.Error);
}
%>
```

I also suggest you to read [this good discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/51213b5d-29db-4237-910e-493df070b095) 
**Edit #1:** Another solution for your case is to 
Create a new page  to hold the UltraWebGridExcelExporter, and in your main page, create a iframe tag to hold that new page. Let the iframe postback. And also upgrade your Infgraistics version to latest.

Comment: Do you think, it 'll behave OK in Case of large data set. If we try to get response directly and tries to export it in excel then it may cause memory IO Exception. Would you like to explain it please ?

Comment: OK,Sure. I 'll try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to relook at the code how you wrote. you need to refactor or improve the codebase.

if you want to increase the request timeout, then you can do this 
you need to add more timeout duration in web.config

```
   <system.web>
        <httpruntime executionTimeout="4800"/> //or higher values
    </system.web>
```

Comment: Code is updated in question description.
If we increase execution time then it 'll only increase ability to receive response, but it 'll not fix the performance issue.